# How can I insert a dictionary that points to multiple dictionaries inside a list

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

can anyone please help me with the following code:

```
[{k: {x: y for x, y in b.items()} for b in arg for k in range(len(arg))}]
```

Where arg is:

```
arg = [{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}, {"key1": "val3", "key2": "val4"}]
```

The output Im looking for is:

```
[0: {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}, 1: {"key1": "val3", "key2": "val4"}]
```

When I run the above dict comprehension, I get

```
[0: {"key1": "val3", "key2": "val4"}, 1: {"key1": "val3", "key2": "val4"}]
```

Why does the second dict that `1:` points to gets repeated at the `0:` spot as well? How can I stop this from happening and have both the nested dicts with their independent values. The keys are the same in both the nested dicts, but the values must differ.

Comment: You have a double loop over `k` and `b`. Instead you need a single loop `for k,b in enumerate(arg)`.

Comment: the output you are looking for is not a valid Python object though... And you have a typo in `arg` (comma needs to be semicolon)

Comment: IMHO your logic is too complex to put into one comprehension. It is not readable anymore and: "Readability counts." —The Zen of Python

Comment: @Klaus `{k:b for k,b in enumerate(arg)}` would be simpler ;)

Comment: `dict(enumerate(arg))` would do what you want.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis why is the output not a valid Python object?

Comment: @KabirGandhiok try `[0: 1]`. Maybe OP means `{0: 'blabla'}` or `[{0: 'blabla'}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-complicating matters. Just use the [`enumerate()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), it produces your key-value pairs *out of the box*:

```
dict(enumerate(arg))
```

`dict()` takes an iterable of key-value pairs:

```
>>> arg = [{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}, {"key1": "val3", "key2": "val4"}]
>>> dict(enumerate(arg))
{0: {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}, 1: {'key1': 'val3', 'key2': 'val4'}}
```

The dictionaries in `arg` are not copied; if that's an issue, you can use a `map()` over `dict.copy`:

```
dict(enumerate(map(dict.copy, arg)))
```

or use a single dictionary comprehension:

```
{i: a.copy() for i, a in enumerate(arg)}
```

Your code created a double loop; you are essentially doing this:

```
_dictionary = {}
for b in arg:
    for k in range(len(arg)):
        _dictionary[k] = {x: y for x, y in b.items()}
result = [_dictionary]
```

so for every dictionary in `arg` you create *another* loop and repeatedly create a dictionary for `b`. The last such dictionary for `k` will win, and as the last dictionary in `arg` is assigned to both `0` and `1` it replaces any other dictionary in `arg` (which where each also assigned to all integer keys before).

You didn't need to use `{x: y for x, y in b.items()}` either, just `b.copy()` would have sufficed. I'm also not sure why you put the final result into a list.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that so well. I had not thought about the enumerate function. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Small problem with the output you want. You want a `Dictionary` while your

> The output Im looking for is:
>
> [0: {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2"}, 1: {"key1": "val3", "key2":
>   "val4"}]

is a `list`. So, the valid output should be :

> {0: {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}, 1: {'key1': 'val3', 'key2':
>   'val4'}}

Obtain this with :

```
{ i:l[i] for i in range(len(l)) }

# OR

{ i:key for i,key in enumerate(l) }
```

#driver values

```
IN : l = [{"key1":"val1", "key2":"val2"}, {"key1":"val3", "key2":"val4"}]
OUT : {0: {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}, 1: {'key1': 'val3', 'key2': 'val4'}}
```

Edit: [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662898/7550472) provides shorter method using `enumerate`. Check it out too.

Answer (score 0):

If I have interpreted this correctly you want a dictionary of dictionaries. This will do that:

```
{index: val.copy() for index, val in enumerate(arg)}
```

Where `arg` is your predefined dictionary.

EDIT: What user [Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46662898/8745437) put above is a neat way of doing this!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite complex. How about:
`[{k: arg[k]} for k in range(len(arg))]`